# In android Studio Image is not showing in preview

Tags: image, android-layout, imageview, preview, android-studio-3.0

I'm using `ImageView` in **AndroidStudio** but **AndroidStudio** doesn't show my image in the preview. Please find the below screenshot:

[image: Screen shot]

Answer (score 0):

Go to styles.xml and add "Base" as below.

[image]

I hope it helps!